# High pitched acoustic reverb from semi circle monument

Tags: acoustics

I went on a trip last week and encountered a rather peculiar phenomenon [here](https://www.google.com/maps/uv?pb=!1s0x1501f24f07175b83%3A0xc4940a26a21f4c3b!3m1!7e115!4s!15sCgIgAQ&imagekey=!1e10!2sAF1QipM_v3IpYLB63Eu7u6QAwiJh579zK3wKtGGO0z5e), when standing in the middle of the circle that's marked by the bricks, and clapping my hands, a very high pitched noise would seem to emanate from my hands, like a squeak from a toy duck.

This is a rough sketch of the place:

[image: Sketch]

There's a semi-circle concrete bench on one side and the other some sort of statue.

I tried to investigate the location and here are my findings:

1. This happens with claps, stomps, and when breaking dry branches.
2. There's no echo when talking or playing sounds
3. Reports from a friend imply that the effect doesn't reproduce when blocking with one's body the statue.
4. I wasn't able to record it to add a sound sample here.

My current hypothesis is that the sound travels from my hands to the statue, echoed in a higher pitch, and then the concrete bench acts as an acoustic lens that focuses its focal point.

Any other ideas?

Comment: You're probably right: a hand-clap is (crudely) a delta-function, so the bench, possibly in concert with the statue, happens to resonate (or reflect constructively)  at some particular frequencies, and the increased amplitude of those frequencies is what you perceive.

Comment: The thing is, that I've been to places with circular features in them that have a distinct acoustic reverb, but never did the pitch changed

Answer (score 0):

My comment was too long so I turned it to an answer.

Waves with different frequencies interact differently with a structure due to the relation between the size of the structure and the wavelength (see this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/556739/53167)).

Thus, you have different regimes:

- For low frequencies you would have a wave that it is not that affected by your semicircle. This is the main reason of using just one speaker for sub-woofers, they are not that directional because of the large wavelengths-
- For mid frequencies you have really complex behavior involving diffraction and reflection.
- For high frequencies, it is common to consider only reflection and you have a regime of "geometric acoustics".

The frequency/wavelength limits for these regimes are not absolute and they would depend on relative sizes for the structure and wavelength.